# Unable to catch JsonMappingException in Exception Handler

Tags: java, spring, rest, api, exceptionhandler

I have a rest api written in Java (spring boot), my request takes a json string from request header(do not ask why this way:),  e.g. {flowerId: 123}
In my controller, I map the string to object. 
So when users pass in junk data, e.g. {flowerId: abc}, JsonMappingException will be thrown.  I'd like to handle the exception in my exception handler but unable to catch it in my handler. Did I miss something? thanks

See my code below.

```
   @RestController
    public class FlowerController  {
       @GetMapping
        @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
        public GetFlowerResponse getFlowers(@RequestHeader(name = Constants.myHeader) String flowerIdString) throws IOException {
            GetFlowerRequest getFlowerRequest = new ObjectMapper().readValue(flowerIdString, GetFlowerRequest.class);
            //get Flower info with request ...
        }
    }


    @RestControllerAdvice
    public class ApplicationExceptionHandler {
        @ExceptionHandler(value = {JsonMappingException.class})
        @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
        public GetFlowerResponse processServletRequestBindingException(HttpServletRequest req, ServletRequestBindingException e) {
            return buildExceptionResponse(e, ErrorMessages.INVALID_REQUEST.getCode(), e.getMessage());
        }

        @ExceptionHandler(value = Exception.class)
        @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
        public GetFlowerResponse processUnhandledExceptions(HttpServletRequest req, Exception e) {
            return buildExceptionResponse(e, ErrorMessages.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE.getCode(), ErrorMessages.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE.getDescription());
        }
    }   

    public class GetFlowerRequest {
        int flowerId;
    }

public class GetFlowerResponse {
    private List<ReturnDetail> returnDetails;
}

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class ReturnDetail {
    @Builder.Default
    private Integer code = 0;

    @Builder.Default
    private String message = "";

    private String source;
```

Comment: i'm not seeing anything wrong in your code, can you update the error response, and make sure spring scans `Handler` class and create bean

Comment: If the format of the JSON is not correct a `JsonParseException` exception will be raised. If the format of the JSON is correct, but the inputs are not valid (example: String is passed where integer is expected), then `JsonMappingException` is usually raised. Probably you should catch `JsonParseException` as well.

Comment: thanks, response updated

Answer (score 0):

Your exception handler is invalid. Your method `processServletRequestBindingException()` declares `ServletRequestBindingException` exception as parameter but is annotated for `@ExceptionHandler(value = {JsonMappingException.class})`. This exception types must be compatible, otherwise it won't work and you will get an exception during exception handling.

`new ObjectMapper().readValue()` throws both `JsonParseException` and `JsonMappingException`. Both extend `JsonProcessingException` so you most likely need a handler for this exception to cover both cases:

```
@ExceptionHandler(JsonProcessingException.class)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
public GetFlowerResponse handleJsonProcessingException(
        HttpServletRequest req, JsonProcessingException ex) {
   ...
}
```

Do note that it's preferable to autowire `ObjectMapper` from the Spring context and don't create a new instance.

Comment: But my doubt at least it should go to exception method right

Comment: @Karol Dowbecki,  I tried with your advise i.e. adding another method handleJsonProcessingException, still not working,  not able to catch. and not even be caught in processUnhandledExceptions either

Comment: @toosensitive you also must remove existing handler for `JsonMappingException` for this to work as `JsonProcessingException` is more generic. Possibly your `@RestControllerAdvice` is not registered by Spring but there is no way to tell from your small example.